# Can I has [meta.so]?

Tags: feature-request, magic-links

Since the meta split, we don't have a magic link for meta.stackoverflow.com.

Requests in comments are being ignored, so here it is in question format.

### Give us [meta.so]!

<sup>[careers] would be nice, too.</sup>

Comment: When these are linkified, you can mark this status-complete: [meta.so] [careers]

Comment: `[meta]` will work when on [so].

Comment: @Oded yeahbutstill

Comment: @Won't: and next you'll ask for `[meta.programmers.se]` and `[meta.arquade]` and `[meta.mo]` (Meta Math Overflow). Where will it all end?!

Comment: @MartijnPieters it ends with [meta.so] and [careers]

Comment: @Won't: thatswhattheyallsay is what I say.

Comment: There is a grammar error in the title – it has to be “I can has [meta.so]?“.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft it's a joke.  Go search for "can i has cheezburger"

Comment: @Won’t: I know, but it’s [I can has cheezburger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Can_Has_Cheezburger%3F). So you got the wrong grammar wrong.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft that's how that particular company has it, but they didn't invent the meme, and they aren't the arbiter of what is and is not proper cheezegrammar.  So stick it.

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand the reason why you need [meta.so]. It is now usual per site meta and can be accessed from the main site with [meta]. Nothing especially important now discussed on meta.SO, at least not more important than on meta.SU or meta.SF...

[image]

With [careers] I would agree, ok.

Comment: Simple use case: Can't magic link to meta.so from here.  I've wanted to use it several times, but each time had to edit my comment to fix.  There isn't any real reason not to create it; the code needs no change, only a new value->url added to the current list.  No big woop.

Comment: Stack Overflow is the biggest site in the network and its meta is the biggest as well among all others. Many questions here are still relevant to MSO.